# echo value using label as ID in PHP

Tags: php, schema

I am trying to fix the address that appears in Google's SCHEMA testing tool. However, each time I try to change the PHP code, it does not recognize the fields which are already in place and ignores them. The static values work, but I am unable to call the values dynamically. The page which I am trying to achieve this is here: http://jobwalkins.in/walkins/264-senior-associate-walkin-at-dell.html

I have tried to switch the code in different ways but had no luck.

if($_extfield->label == 'Job Location') {

```
if( ! empty ($_extfield->value)  ) {

    echo '<span itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" style="display:none;">
        <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">India</span>';
                echo '<span itemprop="addressRegion">'.$_extfield->value.'</span>';

                if($_extfield->label == 'Walkin Address') {
                        echo '<span itemprop="streetAddress">'.$_extfield->value.'</span>';
                        } 
                        else {
                            echo '<span itemprop="streetAddress">Stree Address</span>';
                        }
                        echo '<span itemprop="postalCode">None</span> 
                            </span>
                        </span>';

                    } else {

                    echo '<span itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" style="display:none;">
                        <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">';
                    echo '<span itemprop="addressLocality">India</span>';
                    echo '<span itemprop="addressRegion">Region</span>';
                    echo '<span itemprop="streetAddress">Street Address</span>
                    <span itemprop="postalCode">None</span>
                    </span>
                    </span>';
                    }
            }
```

I need to have the following fields mapped under address once we fix the PHP code:

Walkin Locality assigned to streetAddress schema property
Walkin City assigned to addressLocality schema property
Walkin State assigned to addressRegion schema property
Postal Code mapped to postalCode schema property

Here is the SCHEMA Testing result:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fjobwalkins.in%2Fwalkins%2F264-senior-associate-walkin-at-dell.html

I am looking forward to gaining a helpful response.

Best Regards,
Syed H